# Comparison Test For Series of Complex Numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

**For Series of Real Numbers**, we have the following theorem. If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b**_n**\}$ be two sequences of positive real numbers such that $0\geq a_n \geq k\cdot b_n$, for some real number $k$ then

- $\{b_n\}$ converges $\implies$ $\{a_n\}$ converges.
- $\{a_n\}$ diverges $\implies$ $\{b_n\}$ diverges.

**For Series of complex Numbers**, we have no order, hence we have to modify our statement accordingly. 
Let $\{z_n\}$ and $\{w_n\}$ be two sequences of complex numbers.

Let, $|z_n|\leq k |w_n|$ then

- $\sum |w_n|$ is convergent implies $\sum z_n$ is absolutely  convergent.
- ***My Question is: "Can we say that $\sum |z_n|$ is divergent implies $\sum w_n$ is divergent."? *** (What I know is $\sum |z_n|$ is divergent implies $\sum |w_n|$ is not absolutely convergent.)

***Further Question:***

I have a further question: If the statement above is not true then how do we show that **" If a power series $\sum a_nz^n$ is not divergent  at $z=z_0$, then it is divergent for all $z$ satisfying $|z|>|z_0|$"**

Comment: As the answer below shows, you get counterexample with real sequences too; however, if you impose conditions on the arguments of $w_n$ which are the analog of positivity for reals (for example if they belong to the same $\pi-\alpha$ length interval, for all large n and some small fixed positive $\alpha$), you can use standard inequalities that reverse the usual triangle inequality to get a similar result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we cannot. Take $z_n=\dfrac1n$, $w_n=\dfrac{(-1)^n}n$, and $k=1$.

Comment: I have a further related question. WIll you please help me with it.

Comment: That is **another** question. Please post it as such. And if my answer was helpful, you might consider the possibility of accepting it.

Comment: It's kind of related. I hope to prove the second statement one need to use the previous kind of a statement, I will surely accept it.